# How to save the previous state and current state for a barchart in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I built a webapp where the user enters some text and we get some scores and create a barchart based on those scores. However I want to create a grouped barchart now for comparison. Suppose the user change something in the text and we get new score so i want to show this new scores in the bar chart with the previous score. It should compare only the current value and the previous value and not go farther than that. I tried to code this but got error like

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-hooks-9gzid)

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'current' before initialization
```

Editor.js I'm just pasting important parts of the code since it's a big file

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Tabs, Tab, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import BarChart from "../barCharts";

const style2 = {
  flex: 1,
  textAlign: "center"
};

class MainText extends Component {
  state = {
    analysis: {
      tonal: [],
    },
    showButton: false
  };

Analysis = async () => {
    const { enteredText } = this.state;
    const body = { snippetdesc: enteredText };
    const stringifiedBody = JSON.stringify(body);

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: stringifiedBody
    };

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/apicall`;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const result = await response.json();


      const {
        ...tonalAnalysis
      } = result.scores;

      const tonalArray = Object.entries(tonalAnalysis).reduce(
        (carry, [tone, value]) => [
          ...carry,
          { tone: tone.toLowerCase(), value: parseInt(value) }
        ],
        []
      );

      this.setState({
        analysis: { ...this.state.analysis, tonal: tonalArray },
        showButton: true
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error when performing sentiment analysis");
    }
  };

  render() {
    const series = this.state.analysis.tonal.map((tonal) => tonal.value);
    const prev=current;
    const current = series; //error here

    return (
      <div>
        //<textarea>
        //analysis button

        <Button
          className={this.state.showButton ? "showButton" : "hideButton"} //.showButton{visibility: visible}; .hideButton{visibility: hidden}
          onClick={this.showPieModal}
        >
          Show BarChart Modal
        </Button>

        {this.state.showPieModal && (
          <Modal show={this.state.showPieModal} onHide={this.handleClosePie}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Analysis</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body className="pieModal">
              <BarChart data={current} prev={prev}/> 
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClosePie}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainText;
```

BarChart.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "./App.css";

class BarChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("props" + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    this.state = {
      data: {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",

        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            //stack: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: this.props.data
          },
          {
            label: "My second dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(155,231,91,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            //stack: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: this.props.prev
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      type: "bar",
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    };

    return (
      <Bar
        data={this.state.data}
        options={options}
        width={null}
        height={null}
        options={options}
      />

    );
  }
}

export default BarChart;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error explains it, you are trying to access a constant before you initialize it. `const current = series;` is after `const prev = current;`.

But the problem is you are trying to render the previous values without storing them in state. What if your component re-renders? The previous data will be lost.

You want to keep the previous values in state:

```
state = {
    analysis: {
        tonal: [],
    },
    prevAnalysis: {
        tonal: [],
    },
    showButton: false,
};
```

Update when you receive new data:

```
const currAnalysis = // clone this.state.analysis

this.setState({
    prevAnalysis: currAnalysis,
    analysis: { ...this.state.analysis, tonal: tonalArray },
    showButton: true
});
```

Then use the prevAnalysis in your component as prev. You don't need this

```
const prev = current;
const current = series;
```

Generally, everything that is not saved in state will be used for the current render, whenever you want to keep previous values etc. in memory, you store them in state.

Comment: I've updated the sandbox and getting a new error in line 69 in the sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-hooks-9gzid.. not sure if I cloned the state correctly in the api call block. can you please have a look?

Comment: You stored only the tonalArray, the error is thrown because you are trying to access prevAnalysis as an object, not an array. If you just need the array for your BarChart's previous data, you can either change the BarChart accordingly, or you can do `const currAnalysis = { tonal: [...tonalArray]}.

Comment: it does show the grouped bar chart now but the problem is that both the bars are of same values, that is both the grouped bars are showing the current value. It doesn't retain the previous value when I call the api again. Is there a way though which I can still retain the previous value when I make a new api call and then make the comparison?

Comment: It is supposed to retain the previous. What does console.log say when BarChart is rendered? When you setState on the parent component, BarChart should be rerendered with the correct props, both current and previous.

Comment: My mistake, currAnalysis should be {tonal: [...this.state.analysis.tonal]}

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code here:

```
render() {
    const series = this.state.analysis.tonal.map((tonal) => tonal.value);
    const prev=current;
    const current = series; //error here
```

Your code trying to access value `current`, and after that you are declaring it using `const`.

Comment: yeah I figured that out. but how am I suppose to store the current value somewhere so that in the next analyze, it becomes the previous value and the new values are used as current values. This looks more like a fibonacci type problem but I'm not able to figure out the entire picture